# images instead of radio buttons

Tags: html, css, forms, webforms

i have been trying to customize my radio button and for that i want to know how can i simply add images on check and unchecked event of radio button and it should be generic for all browsers i tried various functionalities but all give results but with certain defect all i am trying to do there is css that convert all the raio buttons as specified kindly let me know how it can be done by using css approach only (I did it already with jquery but the defect it requires a label for eash radio button and always keep float to left)

Kindly help
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS for that:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:20px;
}

input[type="radio"], .notchecked {
    background:url("notchecked.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked, .checked {
    background:url("checked.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

If you want older browsers to use it, you can add this with jquery:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    }
});
$("input[type=radio]:checked").addClass("checked");
```

and the html:

```
<input type="radio" class="notchecked" value="true" />
```

Comment: for using jquery do i have to include any header file?

Comment: moreover for using it for radio button i have to replace checkbox with radio right?

Comment: @softgenic you are right I updated the code. You will have to add jquery to your page, yes.